# Does BasicNameValuePair allow duplicate keys?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I want to know if BasicNameValuePair allows duplicate keys?

Comment: @canolucas, could you please consider refraining from just going round looking for thanks to remove? See discussion on this topic [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168190/130064)...

Comment: @Benjol, sure. i didn't know it wasn't accepted in the community to do such fixes. no problem.

Comment: @canolucas, read the link (if you haven't already). It *is* accepted, as long as it's in the context of a bigger/better correction. Otherwise it just creates more work for the (three) people who have to review each edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put one key and value in an `BasicNameValuePair`. So you can't have duplicate keys! Or do you mean if you could have two of them with the same key? Then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

BasicNameValuePair is just a simple wrapper around two Strings (a name and a value). There's no way of adding more than that, so duplicate keys doesn't really make sense. There are no keys, as such, just a single name.